When implementing Firebase social login with Flutter, encountering issues such as empty user credentials after logging in through Apple
When implementing Firebase social login with Flutter, particularly integrating Sign in with Apple, I'm encountering issues where the user credentials returned after logging in through Apple are empty. Despite successful authentication, the user data seems to be missing or incomplete. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue effectively? Additionally, are there any specific considerations or best practices when implementing Firebase social login with Flutter, especially with platforms like Apple?
Heres my datasource
    @override
    Future<UserCredential> signInWithApple() async {
    await checkNetwork(networkInfo);
    try {
      final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
      appleProvider..addScope('email')
        ..addScope('name');

      UserCredential userCredential = await firebaseAuth.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);

        return userCredential;

    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      throw GeneralError(title: 'Apple Sign-In', message: error.message);
    } catch (error) {
      throw GeneralError(
          title: "Apple Sign-In", message: "Some thing went wrong",stackTrace: error.toString());
    }
    }

Heres my getxcontroller method

     Future<void> loginWithApple(BuildContext context) async {
     appleLoadingState = LoadingState.loading;
     update([updateEmailScreen]);

     await authenticationSource.signInWithApple().then((userCredential) {
    
      isLoggedIn = true;
      customError = null;
      user = userCredential.user;
      email = null;
      password = null;
      Get.back();
      update();
      appleLoadingState = LoadingState.loaded;
      update([updatedAuthWrapper, updateEmailScreen]);
      }).onError<CustomError>((error, stackTrace) {
      user = null;
      customError = error;
      appleLoadingState = LoadingState.loaded;
      update([updatedAuthWrapper, updateEmailScreen]);
      getErrorDialog(error);
      });
      }


I tried the above code but im getting empty credentials.

It seems you are following the wrong documentation for Firebase Authentication. If you are developing in Flutter then it will work with FirebaseAuth.
Here is the Link -

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start

If you still need help let me know.
